# CA2122 : Microsoft.Security : 'User.EmployeeId.get()' calls into 'PropertyValueCollection.Value.get()'

Tags: code-analysis

```
 Warning    76  CA2122 : Microsoft.Security : 'User.EmployeeId.get()' calls into 'PropertyValueCollection.Value.get()' which has a LinkDemand. By making this call, 'PropertyValueCollection.Value.get()' is indirectly exposed to user code. Review the following call stack that might expose a way to circumvent security protection:
```

->'User.EmployeeId.get()'
   ->'User.EmployeeId.get()'    C:\WiproDaas\WiproDaas\DirectoryService\User.cs 105 DirectoryService

```
 public string EmployeeId
    {
        get { return this["employeeID"].Value as string; }
        set { if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) this["employeeID"].Value = value; }
    }
```

Hi, i am facing warning near get(),please help me how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trust issue. Try adding the following attribute to EmployeeId:

```
[EnvironmentPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Unrestricted = true)]
```